# "sync source prob lem: 10278 dbclient error communicating with server"

Tags: mongodb

## Problem

MONGODB v2.4.8 three node replica set.

"replSetGetStatus" from mgo2 reports:

> mgo2 PRIMARY       sync source problem: 10278 dbclient error communicating mgo4
>
> mgo3 SECONDARY     (blank)
>
> mgo4 SECONDARY     (blank)

replSetGetStatus from mgo3 reports:

> mgo2 PRIMARY      (blank)
>
> mgo3 SECONDARY       syncing to: mgo2
>
> mgo4 SECONDARY       syncing to: mgo2

replSetGetStatus from mgo4 reports:

> mgo2 PRIMARY         (blank)
>
> mgo3 SECONDARY       (blank)
>
> mgo4 SECONDARY      syncing to: mgo2

Note the OPTIME is the same from all nodes for all nodes.

## Questions

1) what does the error "sync source problem: 10278 dbclient error communicating mgo4" mean.

2) how do i troubleshoot it?

Thank you

Scott

Comment: If you can share the actual output from rs.status() for each of the replica set members that would make it much easier for us to help you debug this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have not posted a reply to date as the PRIMARY MGO2 rebooted due to a patch update an MGO4 was elected the new PRIMARY. The issue is no longer visible to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB replica set members are constantly sending heartbeats (pings) to other members every two seconds. If a heartbeat doesn't return within 10 seconds, the other members mark that member as inaccessible.

The error you are getting is because there was a problem in communication between the primary and the secondary replica set members. 
That could have been a temporary network problem or the server experienced a huge load and didn't respond in time.

You should check the logs on your servers to get a better insight about what went wrong.